# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, database

I am beginner in asp.net, and I developed a web site that uses DB, but I always got this exception when trying to connect to the databse:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = (local)\\ASP2010;Database = accedint_DB;Integrated Security = true");

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "select EMPLOYEE_ID from EMPLOYEE_INFO where USER_NAME = @Name and USER_PASS = @Pass";


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", textBox2.Text);


    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)con.Open();


    string UserID;
    UserID = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());

    if (UserID =="")
        MessageBox .Show ("Login fail , Please try again");

     else if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "admin")
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(UserID);
            f2.EmpName = textBox1.Text;
            f2.Show();
        }
    else if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "employee") {
        Form10 f10 = new Form10();
        f10.EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(UserID);
        f10.EmpName = textBox1.Text;
        f10.Show();

    }

    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "admin")
    {
        Form5 f2 = new Form5();

        f2.EmpName = EmpName;

        f2.Show();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "employee") {

        Form4 f10 = new Form4();
        f10.EmpName = EmpName;
        f10.Show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in debug mode? On which line does the error occur?

Comment: at this statement   con.Open();

Comment: I put the code in try catch and then I had got the msg:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I think that because a problem in sql server, I don't know what is the error in sql server

Comment: another thing please, can you help me on how to open and view the tables in mdf database

Comment: It's a database connection issue by the sound of it. Your connection string is wrong I suspect. Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed?

Comment: You can view your database in Visual Studio in server explorer. Just create new data connection to the database file.

Comment: the above visual studio server explorer helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Read this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa952081.aspx) under following topic:

**Error "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake" occurs when connecting to remote SQL Server databases on SQL Server 2008**

Hope it helps.